# I couldn't able to delete products from my cart

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am Using this code

````
   return _firebaseServices.productsRef.doc(_firebaseServices.getUserId())
       .collection("Users").doc(widget.documentId)
       .collection("Cart").doc(widget.productId)
       .delete();
  }```
````

Comment: What error do you get? Are userID, documentId and product ID defined?

Comment: Yes I have defined. I couldn't delete the data from cloud firestore database

Comment: What's in `_firebaseServices.getUserId()` ?